# Mismatch between node version in console vs node version in process.version?

Tags: node.js, nvm

I have NVM to manage node versions, and I need to use 6.10 for a current project.

When I node -v in terminal I get, v6.10.3. When I run nvm alias default I get default -> 6.10 (-> v6.10.3). In my IDE, Webstorm, I have my Node interpreter set to 6.10.3, and in my package.json I have:

```
"engines":{"node":"6.10.3"}
```

However, in my project itself when I run

```
console.log(process.version);
```

I get v4.3.2. What am I doing wrong? How can I switch to 6.10.3 in my actual project?

Thanks!

Comment: How do you run your project? Did you try the full command `nvm alias default 6.10.3` ? Can you post screenshot of WebStorm setup?

Comment: The project is a lambda function, so its run locally with docker-lambda. Yes, I ran that command which is why 6.10.3 is the default nvm alias default. What in my setup would be helpful with a screenshot? The main problem as far as I can tell is that process.version shows the wrong version, so where exactly is process.version set and how can I change it?

Comment: So if you run is with `docker-lambda` - are you running `lambci/lambda:nodejs6.10` docker image ?

Comment: @no_parachute44 `process.version` is a read only variable set by node which you cannot modify (and if you could, there would be no point in doing so), thus for some reason you really launch node.js with version 4.3.2.

Answer (score 1):

(nvm maintainer here)

The engines field in package.json is purely advisory, and nvm does not pay attention to it. You can add an `.nvmrc` file to your project with your desired version number; however, you’ll still need to manually `nvm use` to activate it (see the project readme for ways to make it auto-use on `cd`, which is too intrusive to do by default).